# How can i storage the logging information (from python module) into SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, sqlite, handler

First of all, sorry for my English.

i'm using Python3.x. I want to create a handler that storage the current logging

information into a table in SQLite3.

i've a handler that show by console de current logging and another that write the

same into a txt file.

I leave you my example:

---

import logging

class Logger(object):
    '''test logger'''

```
def __init__(self):
    '''constructor'''
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('CIRE')
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    formatter = '%(asctime)s. %(name)s|%(levelname)s| %(message)s'
    dateFormat = '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'
    logging.basicConfig(format=formatter, datefmt=dateFormat, filename='Logger.log')

    formatter = logging.Formatter(formatter, dateFormat)

    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    self.logger.addHandler(ch)
```

l = Logger()
 l.logger.debug("test")

OUTPUT:
02/07/2017 12:54:13 PM. CIRE|DEBUG| test

---

thanks!!

Comment: A number of people seem to have written things like this, including https://github.com/amka/SQLiteHandler and https://gist.github.com/ykessler/2662203. I haven't used either of these, I don't know how good they are. However, you might get some useful ideas from them.

Comment: Thanks!, It has been useful to me

Comment: You're very welcome!